# when I use onEdit function my code stop working?

Tags: google-apps-script

my code works well using `myFunction()` but just when I change it to `onEdit` and use `e.range` and column number to restrect the working within specific column it stops

```
function onEdit(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Timesheet & Feedback");

var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
var cellContent = cell.getValue();
var Manaf = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("manaf652@gmail.com");
var MustafaSmeer = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("8q65ner19m8uk8idmmkmrr2hvs@group.calendar.google.com");
var activeRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
var data = ss.getRange("A" + activeRow + ":G" + activeRow).getValues();

var range = e.range;
var CellColumn = range.getColumn();

if (CellColumn == 2) {


    if (cellContent === "Mustafa Sameer") {
        MustafaSmeer.createEvent(data[0][0], data[0][2], data[0][2], {
            description: "First call " + data[0][0]
        });
        MustafaSmeer.createEvent(data[0][0], data[0][4], data[0][4], {
            description: "Second call " + data[0][0]
        });
        MustafaSmeer.createEvent(data[0][0], data[0][6], data[0][6], {
            description: "Third call " + data[0][0]
        })
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation:

Your simple trigger doesn't have authorisation to access `CalendarApp`. They run with "LIMITED" `authMode`, not "FULL" like when you're running the script manually.

This is why your script isn't running properly anymore, as soon as you took it out of a manual/time based trigger with your permission to run, then replaced it with a simple trigger, it lost the authorisation it needs to run succesfully. Please see the references below for more details on the permissions of each trigger type.

---

#### References:

1. [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
2. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

---

#### Solution:

Use an installable `onEdit()` trigger instead. To do this, go into your project's triggers, add a new trigger and set it to run when the spreadsheet is edited. You'll then be asked to authorise the script, this will allow it to run as you're expecting, because you have given it your authorisation explicitly.

**Note**: Make sure to rename your function so that you don't get any spurious extra triggers.

---

#### Reference:

1. [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: I see that's sad , thank you ver much I really appreciate it

Comment: @ManafA.B I've added a solution section to my answer, this should allow it to run as you're expecting. Please give it a try.