# How to make each function run on specific page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two fuctions with same name "myFunction" I run it using google trigers on edit, and I have two sheet how to specify each one for each sheet I use this but it doesn't work

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy of Timesheet & Feedback");

//and on the other function


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Visits");
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

`getSheetByName()` will return the sheet you're looking for, but has nothing to do with the sheet that is being edited to trigger your function.

---

#### Solution:

Instead you can use event objects for this purpose. Wrap your whole script inside an `if` statement checking the name of the sheet. The new function should look something like this:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() === "Copy of Timesheet & Feedback") {
    //your code here
  }
}
```

This way the code will not continue if it doesn't find the sheet it's expecting (the sheet name inside the `if` statement).

---

#### Notes:

Notice the name of the function `myFunction(event)`, "(event)" is important so that we can access the event object to grab the spreadsheet that is being edited.

You won't be able to run the script manually, set up a trigger for "on Edit" and it'll just run automatically.

---

#### References:

1. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hello Ross, I get this error  TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Visits")

Comment: You won't be able to run the script manually if that's what you're trying. It'll run automatically when the sheet is edited if your trigger is set up correctly.

Comment: I tried doing it from the sheet but the same can you please see the code here 

https://script.google.com/d/1z4PAAkywve3t2rYj9ZYDNrLcTFd0CrNQ22FyOJsIYzGAi71l7l80GwaZ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try deleting the triggers you have set up then re-creating, also you might want to change the function names so that they're not the exact same.

Comment: same Ross, do you think the reason is the same like this one ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692181/when-i-use-onedit-function-my-code-stop-working

Comment: You need installable triggers for this to run - you're accessing `CalendarApp` so it needs extra authorisation. Make sure your triggers are set up correctly and give the functions different names to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I don't know it doesn't work , Ross can I print sheet name to ensure the return is right , is that works ? 
   
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  logger.log(ss.getName());

Comment: Yeah you can test using `Logger.log(ss.getName());` make sure there are no extra spaces and your capitals are correct for your sheet names too in both the `if` statements and the actual sheet names. If you'd like you could share a copy of the sheet, this would help get to the bottom of the issue.